# MvvmCross View Model Lifecycle Restore not working

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross, android-lifecycle

I have a simple **MvvmCross 5.6.3** app where I'm trying navigate from `View A` to `View B`. The `Views'` `Fragments` run in a **single** `MvxAppCompatActivity`.

At the moment I am still using `ShowViewModel` to navigate.

`View B` seems to load ok after navigating to it from `View A`:

1. `ctor` called
2. `OnCreate` called
3. `ViewModel` constructed, initialized and started
4. `OnViewCreated` called and `ViewModel` set

However, a change in orientation causes the following happen:

1. `ViewModel's` `SavedState` called
2. `ctor` called
3. `OnCreate` called
4. `OnViewCreated` called

`View B's` `ViewModel` is set but I have no idea how, as the `ctor` is not called. `Init()`, `ReloadState()` or `Start()` are not called.

`View B` has the `IsCachableFragment` of the `MvxFragmentPresentationAttribute` set to be *false*.

So I would expect a brand new `View` and `ViewModel` to be constructed, and the `ViewModel` to go through the standard lifecycle. **Has anyone got any idea why this does not seem to work?**

**Does MvvmCross 5.0 onward support using `ShowViewModel` (ie 4.x mechanism)?**  I don't mean mixing the two, I mean only using `ShowViewModel` not `MvxNavigationService`).

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the `ViewModel` is not affected in orientation changes in `Mvx`, i.e. it doesn't run the lifecycle again.

[ViewModel's ReloadState](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/viewmodel-lifecycle?scroll=77#restore-state) is meant to be called when your app is coming back to life after tombstoning.

So after orientation changes you have the `ViewModel` in the state it was before the change (unless tombstoning occurs in the middle of the orientation change which is very rare). Why would you want to have a brand new `ViewModel` upon orientation change?

Comment: When I was using 4.x my activity was an MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity, when I rotated the screen it went through the whole construct, Init, ReloadState and Start for every view/ViewModel in the hierarchy. So when I moved to using an MvxAppCompatActivity I expected the same behaviour. So was this a change going to MvvmCross 5.0? If this is the case, I'll have to figure out a new way of tidying up my view model to clear up references to other objects. Previously I was using OnDestroyView, which will not work now as this is called on rotation, so my view model is now not in the correct state.

Comment: I'll dig up to see if it's possible to indicate the viewmodel to not be cached during orientation change. If not you can have a `Clean()` method on your ViewModel and call `this.ViewModel.Clean()` when detecting orientation change in the `void OnConfigurationChanged (Android.Content.Res.Configuration newConfig)` of your Activity/Fragment to clear up the references of the objects you mention and do some extra work if you want.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it would be great if there was a way of not caching the view model. I have already have a tidy method, the issue is not so much about tidying, but detecting the difference between when the view is no longer needed and a rotation. OnDestroyView is called for both.

Comment: Hi, I found that in MvxFragmentExtensions it has a LoadViewModel which checks the configured Implementation of IMvxChildViewModelCache to see if that type has been cached. If not it will go through the viewmodel lifecycle. IS this a valid approach if I need to go down this road? I'm not sure if this will have any side effects. Also there is MvxSingleViewModelCache and MvxMultipleViewModelCache so I am unsure what to do here.

Comment: I have also noticed that if I navigate to a fragment using ShowViewModel<MyViewModel>, enter data, close the fragment, then Repeat ShowViewModel<MyViewModel> the data is still there, it is reusing the ViewModel. It does not call init or start the second time. This seems like the wrong behaviour. Before upgrading using the MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity this always got me a new ViewModel

Comment: So what I did was I implemted and registered IMvxMultipleViewModelCache and now I get a new view model. However on a container fragment which contains tabs, it attempts to apply the tab item view model to the container view, rather than the container view model. Where in the framework does it decide what view model matches the view

Comment: OK so the problem seems to be that I have fragments used in a tablayout that I just want to manage programatically, e.g construct them using new, set their view model, then use the child fragment manager to set them inside another fragment. However, on restore the  framework wants to reconstruct these and go through the lifecycle, which I don't want. How do I get MvvmCross to ignore these. At the moment I have tried not decorating the fragments with MvxFragmentPresentationAttribute, and I have tried with the attribute with no parameters. Neither work. Can anyone help?

Comment: I have asked another question as a follow-up. It explains how I have solved the immediate problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49367567/mvvmcross-5-6-3-use-fragment-programattically-outside-of-all-caching

Answer (score 1):

I have posted a solution to my problem here [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49367567/mvvmcross-5-6-3-use-fragment-programattically-outside-of-all-caching). However there must be a better way of doing this, ao that this the point of the follow up.